# Copy paste data from one sheet to another and only pick filtered data and maintain target column sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to automate a step to copy data from one sheet to another using excel macro.
But below are the problem I am facing with this requirement:

1. Need to copy paste in scope data i.e. filter on 'Data Scope' = Yes
2. Column sequence of source and target are different and since there are around 127 columns so could not hardcode this part.

Please help if you have a handy code or logic to implement the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. A list of requirements is not asking a question ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: An idea: Write source headers to array (`sHeaders`). Write destination headers to array (`dHeaders`). Write source data (including headers) to array (`sData`). Use something like `hMatches = Application.Match(sHeaders, dHeaders, 0)` to get the indexes and then using a loop, write the appropriate values to `sData`, which is becoming the destination array. Finally, write the partial destination array to the destination range. This is at least 10 questions in one so without your attempt this is not going to happen. Try asking questions of a smaller scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple way to implement this, posting it here for others to use.

```
Sub Reorganize_columns()

    Dim v As Variant, x As Variant, findfield As Variant
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iNum As Long
    Dim sht_source As Worksheet, sht_target As Worksheet
    
    
    Set sht_source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set sht_target = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")
    
    sht_source.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"
    
    Set rng = sht_target.Range("A1:HS1")
    
    For Each cell In rng
        iNum = iNum + 1
        findfield = cell.Value
        Set oCell = sht_source.Rows(1).Find(What:=findfield, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        sht_source.Columns(oCell.Column).Copy
        sht_target.Columns(iNum).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    Next cell
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```